# Data are not replicated between MongoDB instance (replication in docker compose)

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

i’m trying to setup a replicat between 3 MongoDB instance in a Docker environnement. All instances of MongoDB seems to works well. I’m able to be connected to thoses instances with Compass. The replicat seems also to works, a primary is elected and nothing in the logs altert me of a potential problem.

Here is the rs.conf() output:

```
{
  _id: 'rs0',
  version: 1,
  term: 3,
  members: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      host: 'mongo1:30001',
      arbiterOnly: false,
      buildIndexes: true,
      hidden: false,
      priority: 1,
      tags: {},
      secondaryDelaySecs: Long("0"),
      votes: 1
    },
    {
      _id: 1,
      host: 'mongo2:30002',
      arbiterOnly: false,
      buildIndexes: true,
      hidden: false,
      priority: 1,
      tags: {},
      secondaryDelaySecs: Long("0"),
      votes: 1
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      host: 'mongo3:30003',
      arbiterOnly: false,
      buildIndexes: true,
      hidden: false,
      priority: 1,
      tags: {},
      secondaryDelaySecs: Long("0"),
      votes: 1
    }
  ],
  protocolVersion: Long("1"),
  writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault: true,
  settings: {
    chainingAllowed: true,
    heartbeatIntervalMillis: 2000,
    heartbeatTimeoutSecs: 10,
    electionTimeoutMillis: 10000,
    catchUpTimeoutMillis: -1,
    catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis: 30000,
    getLastErrorModes: {},
    getLastErrorDefaults: { w: 1, wtimeout: 0 },
    replicaSetId: ObjectId("646dd34139abd7f32bb09ea1")
  }
}
```

And the rs.status():

```
{
  set: 'rs0',
  date: 2023-05-24T10:01:40.074Z,
  myState: 2,
  term: Long("3"),
  syncSourceHost: 'mongo2:30002',
  syncSourceId: 1,
  heartbeatIntervalMillis: Long("2000"),
  majorityVoteCount: 2,
  writeMajorityCount: 2,
  votingMembersCount: 3,
  writableVotingMembersCount: 3,
  optimes: {
    lastCommittedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1684922497, i: 1 }), t: Long("3") },
    lastCommittedWallTime: 2023-05-24T10:01:37.139Z,
    readConcernMajorityOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1684922497, i: 1 }), t: Long("3") },
    appliedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1684922497, i: 1 }), t: Long("3") },
    durableOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1684922497, i: 1 }), t: Long("3") },
    lastAppliedWallTime: 2023-05-24T10:01:37.139Z,
    lastDurableWallTime: 2023-05-24T10:01:37.139Z
  },
  lastStableRecoveryTimestamp: Timestamp({ t: 1684922447, i: 1 }),
  electionParticipantMetrics: {
    votedForCandidate: true,
    electionTerm: Long("3"),
    lastVoteDate: 2023-05-24T09:30:57.058Z,
    electionCandidateMemberId: 1,
    voteReason: '',
    lastAppliedOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1684920580, i: 1 }), t: Long("2") },
    maxAppliedOpTimeInSet: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1684920580, i: 1 }), t: Long("2") },
    priorityAtElection: 1,
    newTermStartDate: 2023-05-24T09:30:57.071Z,
    newTermAppliedDate: 2023-05-24T09:30:57.349Z
  },
  members: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      name: 'mongo1:30001',
      health: 1,
      state: 2,
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      uptime: 1846,
      optime: [Object],
      optimeDurable: [Object],
      optimeDate: 2023-05-24T10:01:37.000Z,
      optimeDurableDate: 2023-05-24T10:01:37.000Z,
      lastAppliedWallTime: 2023-05-24T10:01:37.139Z,
      lastDurableWallTime: 2023-05-24T10:01:37.139Z,
      lastHeartbeat: 2023-05-24T10:01:38.263Z,
      lastHeartbeatRecv: 2023-05-24T10:01:38.266Z,
      pingMs: Long("0"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: 'mongo2:30002',
      syncSourceId: 1,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 1,
      configTerm: 3
    },
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: 'mongo2:30002',
      health: 1,
      state: 1,
      stateStr: 'PRIMARY',
      uptime: 1846,
      optime: [Object],
      optimeDurable: [Object],
      optimeDate: 2023-05-24T10:01:37.000Z,
      optimeDurableDate: 2023-05-24T10:01:37.000Z,
      lastAppliedWallTime: 2023-05-24T10:01:37.139Z,
      lastDurableWallTime: 2023-05-24T10:01:37.139Z,
      lastHeartbeat: 2023-05-24T10:01:38.263Z,
      lastHeartbeatRecv: 2023-05-24T10:01:39.779Z,
      pingMs: Long("0"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: '',
      syncSourceId: -1,
      infoMessage: '',
      electionTime: Timestamp({ t: 1684920657, i: 1 }),
      electionDate: 2023-05-24T09:30:57.000Z,
      configVersion: 1,
      configTerm: 3
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: 'mongo3:30003',
      health: 1,
      state: 2,
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      uptime: 1849,
      optime: [Object],
      optimeDate: 2023-05-24T10:01:37.000Z,
      lastAppliedWallTime: 2023-05-24T10:01:37.139Z,
      lastDurableWallTime: 2023-05-24T10:01:37.139Z,
      syncSourceHost: 'mongo2:30002',
      syncSourceId: 1,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 1,
      configTerm: 3,
      self: true,
      lastHeartbeatMessage: ''
    }
  ],
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1684922497, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary(Buffer.from("71462de63bcd84a20b0fd37f9f8ecbeeeeff4646", "hex"), 0),
      keyId: Long("7236672499625230342")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1684922497, i: 1 })
}
```

I have added w=majority in the URI but nothing new.
I think I have misunderstood the way to connect to the replica via MongoDBCompass, I’m using this URI :

```
mongodb://******:******@XX.XX.XX.XX:30001/?replicaSet=rs0&directConnection=true&authMechanism=DEFAULT&authSource=admin&w=majority
```

But shouldn’t I use this URI with the 3 MongoDB instances ?

```
mongodb://******:******@XX.XX.XX.XX:30001,XX.XX.XX.XX:30002,XX.XX.XX.XX:30003/?replicaSet=rs0&authMechanism=DEFAULT&authSource=admin&w=majority
```

When i try this URI, I have this error :

```
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo1
```

Here are the logs :

```
mongo2                        | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-25T07:25:54.887+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"YY.YY.YY.YY:59230","uuid":"fcdd2403-e65a-4572-a505-90a5865b0650","connectionId":70,"connectionCount":13}}
mongo3                        | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-25T07:25:54.887+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"YY.YY.YY.YY:52958","uuid":"5be994ac-1641-4b4f-a6c2-d172dd90125a","connectionId":38,"connectionCount":9}}
mongo1                        | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-25T07:25:54.886+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"YY.YY.YY.YY:36398","uuid":"3403d40f-9766-4897-80e6-7ee9b10cf35d","connectionId":50,"connectionCount":7}}
mongo2                        | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-25T07:25:54.890+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn70","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"YY.YY.YY.YY:59230","client":"conn70","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"5.1.0"},"os":{"type":"Windows_NT","name":"win32","architecture":"x64","version":"10.0.22621"},"platform":"Node.js v16.17.1, LE (unified)|Node.js v16.17.1, LE (unified)","application":{"name":"MongoDB
Compass"}}}}
mongo3                        | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-25T07:25:54.890+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn38","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"YY.YY.YY.YY:52958","client":"conn38","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"5.1.0"},"os":{"type":"Windows_NT","name":"win32","architecture":"x64","version":"10.0.22621"},"platform":"Node.js v16.17.1, LE (unified)|Node.js v16.17.1, LE (unified)","application":{"name":"MongoDB
Compass"}}}}
mongo1                        | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-25T07:25:54.891+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn50","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"YY.YY.YY.YY:36398","client":"conn50","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"5.1.0"},"os":{"type":"Windows_NT","name":"win32","architecture":"x64","version":"10.0.22621"},"platform":"Node.js v16.17.1, LE (unified)|Node.js v16.17.1, LE (unified)","application":{"name":"MongoDB
Compass"}}}}
mongo2                        | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-25T07:25:54.946+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn70","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"YY.YY.YY.YY:59230","uuid":"fcdd2403-e65a-4572-a505-90a5865b0650","connectionId":70,"connectionCount":12}}
mongo1                        | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-25T07:25:54.946+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn50","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"YY.YY.YY.YY:36398","uuid":"3403d40f-9766-4897-80e6-7ee9b10cf35d","connectionId":50,"connectionCount":6}}
mongo3                        | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-25T07:25:54.947+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn38","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"YY.YY.YY.YY:52958","uuid":"5be994ac-1641-4b4f-a6c2-d172dd90125a","connectionId":38,"connectionCount":8}}
```

I think i’m missing somethings in the initiatial parameters but i d’ont know what.
Any help will be useful.

Thanks,
Mallory LP.